# Strange error while compiling through hadoop

Tags: hadoop, javac

I am probably doing something really stupid to get an error like this

The command I am executing is

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
```

The error is this(nowhere to be found on the net):

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 14: public: command not found
```

BTW, I am following along with this tutorial(https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Purpose) and am having no success in compiling the WordCount class.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME? Also add tools.jar in HADOOP_CLASSPATH

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/kishore/BigData/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```